# Tiny Nav Responsive Issue

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, responsive-design

I'm having an issue getting this responsive nav to work here: http://traviskoenig.brentthelendesign.com/html/. "MENU" is displayed twice and the dropdown items are not being shown. I'm running Tiny Nav Responsive, and my jQuery is below.

```
jQuery(function() {
    // TINY NAV RESPONSIVE
    jQuery('.current_page_parent').addClass('selected');
    jQuery('.current_page_item').addClass('selected');

    var navigation = responsiveNav("#navigation", {
        insert: "before"
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one can be of any help to you unless you specify what problems you encountered. 'Having issues getting it to work' is far from being enough for someone to help.

Answer (score 0):

While looking at your webpage code, I couldn't find the link to the TinyNav script - its not being loaded, it seems.

On your scripts, you should add:

`<script src="tinynav.min.js"></script>`

Please refer to http://tinynav.viljamis.com for complete instruction.